# Rcpp install error using ubuntu 14.04 and R 3.2.3 after removing MRO 3.2.3

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rcpp

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have a problem installing Rcpp after I installed MRO 3.2.3 only to find out that the RevoMath lib did not install. So I had to remove and reinstall R but did not reinstall RStudio.

I researched what I could and read Dirk E's post on R CMD SHLIB which led me to this answer post listed below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389028/5153539

I tried installing with your code and it looked like it was going to work but eventually got the same error as posted below (although I did not try to install Rcpp from the terminal using this method yet).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Error when installing Rcpp in RStudio on ubuntu 14.04:**

> installing source package ‘Rcpp’ ...
>   package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in file.copy(f, instdir, TRUE) : problem copying ./NAMESPACE to /home/briangriner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/NAMESPACE:   Permission denied Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>   cannot open file '/home/briangriner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/DESCRIPTION':
>   Permission denied Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘Rcpp’
>   removing ‘/home/briangriner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is

> `problem copying ./NAMESPACE to /home/briangriner/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/NAMESPACE: Permission denied`

Check the permissions on that `Rcpp` directory, or just remove it and reinstall Rcpp.  As you're on Ubuntu you can also install the (probably a little older) binary package `r-cran-rcpp`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The permission is root on Rcpp and a couple other packages (like gbm?). I'll try this and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked. Used the command      rm -r Rcpp     and then reinstalled Rcpp in RStudio and am back in business. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to know! Feel free to 'upvote' (click on up arrow) and/or 'accecpt' (click on tickmark only you as person who asked the question see) to give feedback -- that is how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. Certainly worthy of the upvote/checkmark.