# Cannot devtools::install_github() with R 3.6.1

Tags: r, devtools

I recently updated from R 3.5.3 to R 3.6.1 and rerun all my script. Unfortunately, I appear not to be able to install packages from GitHub repos. I have a slightly modified package that sits in my GH repo that is necessary for some scripts. With R 3.5.3 everything went smoothly, but with the most recent version I get the following error

```
Downloading GitHub repo ceschi/urcabis@master
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCChTCy\remotes27985bc713f5\ceschi-urcabis-aeb1bdc/DESCRIPTION' (439ms)
-  preparing 'urca': (910ms)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'urca_1.3-0.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.6' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-urca'
Error: Failed to install 'urca' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/EB74A~1.FRA/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCChTCy/file27989b74233/urca_1.3-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried removing all locked directories, installing on older versions of R, but it seems nothing's working. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT/UPDATE**: for some mysterious reason the error solved itself apparently. Thanks to everyone for helping!

Comment: Do you have write access to your `.../R/win-library/3.6`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the message: `Try removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-urca'`

Comment: @MrFlick, it's not a permission issue, I run the whole thing with admin privileges and regular installation of packages works just fine

Comment: @cory Yes, I tried to remove the folder, successfully.. then retrying the installation produced the same result

Comment: There are a few windows specific annoyances that you might need to check: Your outpupt has a mixture of `/` and `\\` as directory separator. Windows has issues when the full path of a directory gets over 110(?) characters long.