# R studio install package Error cannot move 00LOCK Permission denied

Tags: r

I'm trying to install `rlang` package using `Rstudio` but I'm getting this error:

```r
mv: cannot move '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rlang' to '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-rlang/rlang': Permission denied
```

Could anyone help please ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, adding the `--no-lock` option helps

```r
install.packages("rlang", INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot linog. I'm getting this error when I try you formula:

Comment: Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
2020-04-12 04:36:52 :   cannot open file '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rlang/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied
2020-04-12 04:36:52 : Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
2020-04-12 04:36:52 :   cannot open the connection
2020-04-12 04:36:52 : ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package ‘rlang’

Comment: It looks like `R` does not have the (over)writing permission in `usr/local` directory. Maybe the manual procedure proposed by @akrun could be a solution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. what worked for me, after trying everything else

1. Detach packages you are trying to update
2. Physically remove / delete these packages from library
3. Install packages from R-Studio

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to remove the folder with the `/00LOCK-rlang/rlang` and then reinstall the package

```
install.packages('rlang')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. How can I remove it please ?

Comment: @MOMIL  You can just manually remove the directory from that path

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same problem, but I had a similar issue

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘[myhome]/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’ for modifying

Try removing ‘[myhome]/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-vctrs’
```

And I solved it with this [pacman function](https://rdrr.io/cran/pacman/man/p_unlock.html) that attempts to delete a 00LOCK(s) if it exists:

```
install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_unlock()
```

It worked for me! Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on my server and I found that this can be solved by changing the default installation path of R package

Comment: Could you provide more specific detail, and possibly code, to expand upon your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).