# Error message when trying to build website using distill: invalid version specification

Tags: r, r-distill

I have a *distill* website. When I try to hit "Build Website" using RStudio I get this error message:

> Error: invalid version specification '2021.09.0+351' Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both issues are already fixed in development version of **distill**.
It was previously found by us or reported in Github Issues. Don't hesitate to look there when you have trouble, and also test the development v

This issue

```
Error: invalid version specification
```

is caused when you used the last RStudio IDE version.

The blank page issue is caused when using last **rmarkdown** version.

We'll make a patch release to CRAN very soon, but in the meantime, please install the development version of **distill**

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/distill")
```

Comment: Tank you @cderv!

Comment: Answer worked. I had thorny issues installing some dependencies in Win 10. For anyone else having that issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182115/13110995) answer resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a fully satisfactory answer, but I faced the same issue. Running:

```r
rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

on a terminal/command line window does run the command fully. However, the site is created only with blank pages (even though if you check the html source, the page is there, hidden).

I'm tracing the blank pages to the upgrade of the `rmarkdown` package, in my case, from 2.8 to 2.11. This brings with it a new dependency of `jquerylib` which might be a cause of this as well. This has started to happen with the new version of RStudio `2021.09.0 Build 351`. This is consistent with the error message you and I got.

I tried to downgrade `rmarkdown` but every time you knit from RStudio with that version, it forces the upgrade. I think this should be reported as a bug, as it was clearly working before and now there are several issues that all seemed to be linked with all the upgrades (not compiling from inside RStudio, compiling with blank pages).

(I would have added this as a comment rather than a solution, but I do not have enough reputation yet)

Comment: Thank you @jyiow!