# Snakemake installing R package in rule environment: error cannot move 00LOCK permission denied

Tags: r, locking, conda, snakemake

I'm writing a Snakemake pipeline with a rule that will run an R script. This rule has its own environment that looks like this:

```
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - r
 - bioconda
dependencies:
 - r-base = 4.1.1
 - r-ggplot2 = 3.3.5
 - r-biocmanager = 1.30.16
```

Next to the above packages, I also need [ggbio](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggbio.html), which can be installed with `biocmanager`:

```
if(!require(ggbio, quietly=TRUE)){  # if the package is not there, install it
  BiocManager::install("ggbio")
}
```

When executing this rule via Snakemake, initially everything goes right, and most dependencies of the `ggbio` package get installed. However, after some while, I get the following error:

```
...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
mv: cannot move '/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/00LOCK-xml2/00new/xml2' to '/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/xml2': Permission denied
ERROR:   moving to final location failed
ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘biomaRt’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/biomaRt’
ERROR: dependency ‘biomaRt’ is not available for package ‘GenomicFeatures’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/GenomicFeatures’
ERROR: dependency ‘GenomicFeatures’ is not available for package ‘VariantAnnotation’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/VariantAnnotation’
ERROR: dependency ‘GenomicFeatures’ is not available for package ‘OrganismDbi’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/OrganismDbi’
ERROR: dependency ‘GenomicFeatures’ is not available for package ‘ensembldb’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/ensembldb’
ERROR: dependencies ‘GenomicFeatures’, ‘VariantAnnotation’, ‘ensembldb’ are not available for package ‘biovizBase’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/biovizBase’
ERROR: dependencies ‘biovizBase’, ‘VariantAnnotation’, ‘GenomicFeatures’, ‘OrganismDbi’, ‘ensembldb’ are not available for package ‘ggbio’
* removing ‘/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/ggbio’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpiQdboR/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Old packages: 'fansi'
Warning messages:
1: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
2: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘biomaRt’ had non-zero exit status
3: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘GenomicFeatures’ had non-zero exit status
4: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘VariantAnnotation’ had non-zero exit status
5: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘OrganismDbi’ had non-zero exit status
6: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘ensembldb’ had non-zero exit status
7: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘biovizBase’ had non-zero exit status
8: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘ggbio’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(ggbio) : there is no package called ‘ggbio’
Execution halted
```

The error seems to originate from this part:

```
mv: cannot move '/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/00LOCK-xml2/00new/xml2' to '/mnt/c/Users/nicks/Documents/variantcallingpipeline/.snakemake/conda/b98e3353bb11024e3652b19a833d9dc8/lib/R/library/xml2': Permission denied
```

I get this error only when I run Snakemake from the Ubuntu app on my Windows. If I run it on the server, it works:

```
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (xml2)
... (and then it continues to the other packages)
```

The versions are the same on the server and local, which is `1.3.3` for `xml2`. I've seen other questions relating to this lock issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174010/r-studio-install-package-error-cannot-move-00lock-permission-denied) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory)), and most of them suggest doing something like this:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')
```

But this doesn't work for me because the package doesn't get installed with `install.packages()`. Adding `options("install.lock"=FALSE)` before the install also doesn't work. Also, when I check the R `library` folder in the environment location, I do not see the `00LOCK` directory.

Any tips? Or is this just a Windows thing that's not easily fixable? Running the installment code in Rstudio does work, but I need the package to get installed in the conda environment, not my standard Rstudio library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML shown is substandard ([incorrect channel order](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels)). But more importantly, it generally does not work well to install anything other than Conda packages in Conda-managed R environments. Fortunately, all Bioconductor packages are on the **bioconda** channel (usually with a `bioconductor-` prefix and all lowercase), hence, everything should work perfectly fine with simply:

```yaml
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - r-base=4.1.1
 - r-ggplot2=3.3.5
 - bioconductor-ggbio
```

Comment: I did not know that the Bioconductor packages are available on the bioconda channel, and this works perfectly. Thank you!