# Cant install nonparaeff package in R version 4.0.2

Tags: r

im new on linux (ubuntu 18.04) and im having issues to install nonparaeff package to R version 4.0.2. when i was using r version 3.6.6 (i dont remeber well) i was fine to install. what would be the reason behind this?
when i try to install the package, i got this output:

`install.packages("nonparaeff)`

```
`Installing package into ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘data.table’, ‘Hmisc’, ‘rms’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/data.table_1.13.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5273400 bytes (5.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Hmisc_4.4-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 746061 bytes (728 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 728 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rms_6.0-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 568050 bytes (554 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 554 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/nonparaeff_0.5-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 14936 bytes (14 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 14 KB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘data.table’ is not available for package ‘Hmisc’
* removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Hmisc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Hmisc’ is not available for package ‘rms’
* removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘Hmisc’, ‘rms’ are not available for package ‘nonparaeff’
* removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/nonparaeff’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nonparaeff’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp3FuDAw/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow! Did you follow the instructions below the first error message? (`Try removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-data.table’`)

Comment: Also, try the solution proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, first of all, thanks for the answer. nope, i didnt, because i was scared to do something wrong, as i did before with other things. How i should i proceed this properly?

Comment: edit: dear @VincentGuillemot, i folowed the steps, especifically "install.packages("nonparaeff", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')"  on the post of your second comment and did worked. Thank you !!