# Why would R Shiny app run indefinitely in R Studio?

Tags: r, windows, shiny, rstudio

I wanted to learn how to build Shiny Apps in R so I started [this beginner-level tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html). However, **when I run the app on my desktop** (*Windows 10 x64, 16GB RAM, 500 GB SSD, i5-3470 CPU, Dual Display*) in `R Studio 1.3.1093`) using `R 4.0.3`, **it loads indefinitely with no error output**. I tried running even the basic built-in examples ([which you could find here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/)) and they also failed to load. The exact same scripts and examples run on my laptop (Windows 10 x64, 8GB RAM, 250 GB SSD; R & R Studio specs the same) without issue. I've reinstalled the shiny package, reinstalled R and R Studio, and changed whether the app runs internally or externally with no success. I did find [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-io-app-not-running-on-a-specific-computer/6177) which seems to have encountered the same issue, but with no solution.

I know it's not much to go on, but I'm at a loss as to the next thing I should check. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out from this [mostly unrelated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory) that there was a file at the path C:/ Users/.../Documents\R\win-library\4.0/ called **00LOCK** which was giving R trouble downloading and updating new packages. I'm not sure how it got there or why R was not telling me there were issues in updating the packages, but the shiny app seems to work perfectly fine now.