# Error when installing "Diffbind" package in R

Tags: r, installation, failed-installation

I was trying to install DiffBind package in R, but it reports to me some errors. Could anyone explain to me how to fix errors and installing properly it?
That's the message:

```
 BiocManager::install("DiffBind")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cloud.r-project.org

Bioconductor version 3.14 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Installing package(s) 'DiffBind'
si installano anche le dipendenze ‘RcppEigen’, ‘RcppNumerical’, ‘apeglm’

apertura URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppEigen_0.3.3.9.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1476004 bytes (1.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.4 MB

apertura URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppNumerical_0.4-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 143327 bytes (139 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 139 KB

apertura URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.14/bioc/src/contrib/apeglm_1.16.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1092965 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

apertura URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.14/bioc/src/contrib/DiffBind_3.4.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6762432 bytes (6.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 6.4 MB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppEigen’
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for package ‘RcppNumerical’
* removing ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppNumerical’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RcppEigen’, ‘RcppNumerical’ are not available for package ‘apeglm’
* removing ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/apeglm’
ERROR: dependency ‘apeglm’ is not available for package ‘DiffBind’
* removing ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/DiffBind’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOMlR7W/downloaded_packages’
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: /usr/lib/R/library
  packages:
    spatial, survival
Messaggi di avvertimento:
1: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
2: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘RcppNumerical’ had non-zero exit status
3: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘apeglm’ had non-zero exit status
4: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘DiffBind’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was also trying to install apeglm, RcppNumerical and RcppEpigen but it returns to me with the same error message of failure installation.
Thank you,
Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R install.packages returns "failed to create lock directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382209/r-install-packages-returns-failed-to-create-lock-directory)

Comment: The error messages suggest to `Try removing ‘/home/posi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppEigen’`. Does that directory exist? Are you able to remove it and try again?